# How to make a object with increasing number of keys dynamically

Tags: javascript, object

I want to make a object with increasing number of keys ,for given number of items n
e.g  n=4 , so I want my object as obj {a1:" ",a2:" ",a3:" ",a4:" "} & my value should be "" empty string .

Comment: Can you please share the code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Why not just use an array instead? Something like: `let a = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"]`

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = {}
for (var i=1; i<=4; i++) {
  obj['a' + i] = "" 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a little function that simply loops and sets keys

```js
function createObj(n = 4, keyPrefeix = 'a') {
  const obj = {};
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    obj[keyPrefeix + i] = '';
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(createObj());
console.log(createObj(10, 'foo'));
```